# Difference between scale factor and depth in camera models?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

What is the difference between scale or depth in a camera model? I understand that scale parameter can make entire 3d scene much larger or smaller affecting all the 3d points in the scene where as depth refers to a specific point in 3d.
It is still confusing because points at different depths along the same ray project to the same point, also differently scaled points also project to the same point. In camera models equations, you there is unknown scale factor, why is it not called/considered as unknown depth instead. How do I better understand this?

Answer (score 0):

> In camera models equations, you there is unknown scale factor, why is it not called/considered as unknown depth instead

If what you mean by camera models equations is the projection of a `3d` point to image space, then the resulting coefficient is indeed an unknown depth, not the scale.

I think what will help clear your confusion is to consider why unknown scale or depth can happen: ***unknown depth arises when you only have a single view of your point, while unknown scale happens when you have multiple views but don't know the magnitude of the baselines between those***.

In case the second part isn't clear, consider the baseline `b` between two views `C_1` and `C_2` which is a `3d` vector. When triangulating two matching points `x_1` (seen in `C_1`) and `x_2` (seen in `C_2`), the exact `3d` point `X` that you'll obtain depends on the magnitude of the baseline. If you already know your baseline the point `X` has the correct value. However, if you are in the monocular case, you will only know the direction of your baseline, that is what you will know is `b*s` where `s==1/norm_2(b)`. However, you will have no knowledge of `s` itself. Therefore, when you triangulate from `x_1` and `x_2`, you will obtain `s*X` instead of `X`.

In the first case (known baseline) you obtained the true depth `D_t(X)=norm(X)`. In the second case, your depth will be `D_s(X)=s*norm(X)`, which you will need to multiply by the scale factor `1/s` to get the true depth. Note that this second case is different from having unknown depths: given two points `X` and `Y`, the ratios `D_s(X)/D_s(Y)` is the same as `D_t(X)/D_t(Y)`, which means that the structural information of the scene is preserved.

In the literature, the term depth often refers to "relative" depth, which corresponds to the `s*norm(X)` above and isn't necessarily on the same scale as the real-world data, but expresses the relative information between scene points correctly. The term scale usually refers to the `s` above which allows converting relative depth to "absolute" depth.